# excel - Splitting cell data into other cells based on a number in the first cell

Tags: excel, row, cell

I have one cell in excel containing the following data

108-0,109-1,110-0,111-2,112-0,113-192,114-87,115-100,116-80,117-60

I need to make a script or if statement, that can split the data from the cell into their own cells.

Like the data:

108-0 would be put into cell A108 with the data 0, and 109-1 would be put into cell A109 with the data 1.

How would that be accomplished? Any hints what I should read about?

Thanks in advance

I forgot to mention that the excel sheet should do it automatically. I i am importing several hundred of those 100-1 values, so they should be put into their own cells automatically.

Result - This worked for me:

```
Sub tst()
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UDF:

```
Function splitThem(r As Range, delimeter As String)
    splitThem = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(r, delimeter))
End Function
```

Just select `A108:A117`, enter next formula in formula bar `=splitThem(A1,",")` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it

**UPD:**

let your values be in `A1:D1` range, than you can use:

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim str As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In Range("A1:D1")
        c.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(str)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(c, ","))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention a minor detail in my question: I forgot to mention that the excel sheet should do it automatically. I i am importing several hundred of those 100-1 values, so they should be put into their own cells automatically.